# Transition of a view controller embedded in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I have a problem with a transition. I am modifying this project https://github.com/xxxAIRINxxx/MusicPlayerTransition in order to have the transition from the right instead of the bottom. This part is fine. My transition comes from the right.

My problem is that I'm embedding the presented modal view controller into a Navigation Controller. I do this so I can use the "pushViewController" function when I click on a cell of my modal view controller.

My hierarchy is as follow. I have a dashboard. From the right, I drag a TableViewController X. If I drag back in the opposite direction, I come back to my dashboard. Fine. Now, If I tap a cell, it pushes a new ViewController Y.

Now, if I am in my new ViewController Y and that I drag back, I come back directly on my dashboard instead of going back to my TableViewController X, as a natural navigation controller should behave.

I did a small project on github that does only that, so you can easily see my entire code.
https://github.com/magohamote/NavigationControllerTransition.git

I understand why it behaves like this, but I would like to know how I can override the transition set on the navigation controller in order to have the normal behaviour of my navigation controller once it is presented.

Another problem I have not been able to solve. On the project I used as a starter (the one from xxxAIRINxxx) the transition is perfectly smooth. On mine, the first time I trigger the transition, it blinks and get stuck. Once I did it once, it is smooth the next time I drag my view. But the first time is always awful. I don't know why either :(

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I ran the project, cant see any blinks ..

Comment: My project of the source project? I'm talking about the NavigationControllerTransition project. It does not blink if you click on the button, it blinks if you drag it. I does not come directly, there is a jump.